# Regex - how to exclude this kind of sql from all sql statements in java?

Tags: java, sql, regex

how to exclude this kind of sql from all sql statements:

`alter table ... column ...`

I wrote a regex but it doesn't work in java:

`alter\s+table\s+.*(?<!\s+column\s+.*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need a lookaround, just use this pattern:

```
alter\s+table\s+.*\bcolumn\b.*
```

Code snippet:

```
String sql = "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;";
if (sql.matches("(?i:alter\\s+table\\s+.*\\bcolumn\\b.*)")) {
    System.out.println("not allowed");
}
else {
    System.out.println("allowed");
}
```

### Demo

Comment: thank you for your respond. but I found another way to do this:^alter\s+table\s+((?!\s+column\s+).)+$

Comment: @Jack Whatever works for you.  My only point was that I don't think you need a lookahead here, unless you prefer it for some reason.

Comment: maybe I didn't make it clear to you. Originally, I wanted to exclude SQL like alter table ... without column options. all in all, this kind of regex came in my mind: ^alter table .* (no column options) .*$

Comment: @Jack And that is a valid approach.  But you could also look for the presence of column options, and then negate that result when making a decision.  It's really up to you.

Comment: the negative regex is the very thing. whatever, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By Simply Replacing all the keywords with '' or ' '

Code :

```
String sql = "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name";

sql.replace("alter").('');

sql.replace("column").(' ');
```